# Button to set selected option in Vue

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button:

```html
<button>
  Small car
</button>
```

When clicked it should set the option of a dropdown to "Small car".

```html
<select>
  <option value="smallcar">Lille personbil</option>
  <option value="mediumcar">Lille varevogn</option>
  <option value="largecar">Mellem varevogn</option>
</select>
```

It seems simple, but I have no clue.

Comment: There is no `vue.js` related code in your question. As such there are many ways to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: _"When clicked it should set the option of a dropdown to "Small car"."_ Why? What code is there that should do that?

Comment: @j08691 Sorry about that, I have edited the values to reflect my button.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I am aware. I am however looking for vue.js solution, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the selected value of a select>, You need to write a JavaScript script.
To change the selected value of a select> in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('selectId').value= 0;
```